# Which library should I reference to use SQLite with Windows 8.1 StoreApp

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime

We want to build a Windows Store app that uses SQLite. But we cannot find a dll which we can reference from our project. We are using Visual Studio 2013.

We installed [SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d04f82f-2fe9-4727-a2f9-a2db127ddc9a) but it doesn't seem to contain a dll which we can reference from our *Class Library (Windows Store apps)*. When referencing the sqlite3.dll from this package we get the following error:

*A reference to 'C:\File Dump\sqlite-winrt81-3080401\Redist\Debug\ARM\sqlite3.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.*

How should we get this to work?

Thanks in advance,

Jacco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Grab the binaries from here](https://sqlite.org/download.html)

Images:

[image]

[image]

[image]